# How to grab a specified number of characters after a part of a specified string?

Tags: python, string

Let's say I have a string defined like this:

```
string1 = '23h4b245hjrandomstring345jk3n45jkotherrandomstring'
```

The goal is to grab the 11 characters (these for example '345jk3n45jk') after a part of the string (this part for example 'randomstring') using a specified search term and the specified number of characters to grab after that search term.

I tried doing something like this:

```
string2 = substring(string1,'randomstring', 11)
```

I appreciate any help you guys have to offer!

Comment: You forgot to include your `substring` function

Answer (score 0):

```
string2 = string1[string1.find("randomstring")+len("randomstring"):string1.find("randomstring")+len("randomstring")+11]
```

Comment: While code-only answers might answer the question, you could significantly improve the quality of your answer by providing context for your code, 
a reason for why this code works, and some references to documentation for further reading.
From [answer]: _"Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."_

Answer (score 0):

In one line, using split, and supposing that your randomstring is unique in your string, which seems to be the case as you worded out the question :

```
string1 = '23h4b245hjrandomstring345jk3n45jkotherrandomstring'
randomstring = 'randomstring'
nb_char_to_take = 11

# split using randomstring as splitter, take part of the string after, i.e the second part of the array, and then the 11 first character
result = string1.split(randomstring)[1][:nb_char_to_take]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple regular expression like this

```
import re

s = "23h4b245hjrandomstring345jk3n45jkotherrandomstring"
result = re.findall("randomstring(.{11})", s)[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string1 = '23h4b245hjrandomstring345jk3n45jkotherrandomstring'
string2 = string1[10:22]
print(string2)

randomstring
```

You could use that. Its called string slicing, you basically count the position of the letters and then the first number before the colon is your starting point the second is your ending point when you enter those position numbers you should get whatever is in-between those position, the last is for a different function I highly suggest you search string slicing on YouTube as my explanation wouldn't really help you, and also search up * *Find string method** those should hep you get the idea behind those functions. Sorry couldn't be of much help hope the videos help.